# Three factor contingency table in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am looking to construct a contingency table for three main effects. These are crime, gender and prior conviction. The response variable is whether or not a lenient sentence was granted.

This is the best I have so far.

```
     Crime Gender Priorconv Yes No
1      Shoplifting    Men         N  24  1
2 Other Theft Acts    Men         N  52  9
3      Shoplifting  Women         N  48  3
4 Other Theft Acts  Women         N  22  2
5      Shoplifting    Men         P  17  6
6 Other Theft Acts    Men         P  60 34
7      Shoplifting  Women         P  15  6
8 Other Theft Acts  Women         P   4  3
```

which was created by the following code

```
table1<-expand.grid(Crime=factor(c("Shoplifting","Other Theft Acts")),Gender=factor(c("Men","Women")),
Priorconv=factor(c("N","P")))

table1<-data.frame(table1,Yes=c(24,52,48,22,17,60,15,4),No=c(1,9,3,2,6,34,6,3))
```

Unfortunately this is not very elegant and so I was wondering if there is another way to present the data more clearly.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe look into `xtabs` and/or `ftable`

Comment: @DominicComtois I like what xtabs does. I tried using xtabs(cbind(Yes,No)~Crime+Gender+Priorconv,data=table1)

Comment: Glad to know! Maybe you can post the code and output as an answer to your own question. I'm sure it would be useful for others in your situation.

Answer (score 4):

For contingency you can use **sample** operator and put it inside function to change the number of strings like

```
factory <- function(i) {
    crime <- sample(c("Shoplifting","Other Theft Acts"),i, replace = TRUE)
    gender <- sample(c("Men","Women"),i,replace = TRUE)
    priorconv <- sample(c("P","N"),i, replace = TRUE)
    table <- data.frame(crime,gender,priorconv)
    return(table)
}
table1 <- factory(20)
```

result:

```
              crime gender priorconv
1       Shoplifting    Men         N
2       Shoplifting  Women         P
3  Other Theft Acts    Men         P
4       Shoplifting    Men         P
5  Other Theft Acts  Women         N
6       Shoplifting  Women         N
7       Shoplifting  Women         P
8       Shoplifting    Men         P
9  Other Theft Acts  Women         P
10      Shoplifting    Men         P
11 Other Theft Acts    Men         N
12 Other Theft Acts    Men         P
13      Shoplifting    Men         P
14      Shoplifting  Women         N
15 Other Theft Acts    Men         N
16 Other Theft Acts    Men         P
17 Other Theft Acts  Women         P
18      Shoplifting  Women         P
19 Other Theft Acts    Men         N
20      Shoplifting  Women         N
```

Comment: The table here has double entries, no?